# Prevent kotlin coroutine from being interrupted even if user navigates away

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-workmanager

In my code, a method performs three API POST and it takes a while for each of those to complete. I'm using kotlin coroutine launch on that method. But I also want the user to be able to navigate away from the page while the task is running. I don't want the task of performing three API calls to be interrupted when navigating away. What is the best way to do that? Is WorkManager the way to go?

Somehow my question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12223485/make-my-android-app-work-even-if-the-user-navigates-away-from-it-how-do-i-do-th) but I need to do it in Kotlin. Is the answers in that post still relevant?

Comment: Can you describe technically what do you mean by `takes a while` and `navigate away`, I mean how much is `a while` and where user `navigate away` from?

Comment: By "navigate away" are you referring to the Android app lifecycle? Take a look at Services

Comment: @NathanMeade, yes. When I go back to the previous activity.

Comment: @YaMiN - It's sending a message to an API and the server takes up to 10 seconds to complete processing and sending back the response.

Comment: Use `GlobalScope` , it is not leak-proof but will get your work done

Comment: @Anshul `GlobalScope` should be used very carefully because you can end up creating too much coroutines

Comment: You just have to launch those coroutines in a scope whose lifecycle is not tied to the lifecycle of the activity you're navigating from. You could make a new scope in the Application class and launch those coroutines using that scope.

Comment: As @J.Grbo mentioned launch the co-routine in a different scope, not with viewModelScope or lifeCycleScope.

Answer (score 0):

You need a Service. Please read this:

https://developer.android.com/guide/background